# How to store data on who rated and recommended a song or item in MySQL/SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

Basically I am trying to keep a record of the number of people who recommended a resource AND also the number of people who recommended a song and per - however I am not sure how to do this in a `relational database`. This is my schema and an example on `SQLFiddle` Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29063/1

This is my DDL:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users(
  userID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  forename VARCHAR(100),
  surname VARCHAR(100),
  PRIMARY KEY(userID)
  );


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Type(
  typeID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  typeName VARCHAR(100),
  PRIMARY KEY(typeID)
  );


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Songs(
    songID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    typeID INT NOT NULL,
    songName VARCHAR(100),
    rating INT,
    recommended TINYINT(1),
    FOREIGN KEY (typeID) REFERENCES Type(typeID),
    PRIMARY KEY (songID)
);

INSERT INTO Users VALUES
(NULL, "Jack", "Son"),
(NULL, "Bob", "Marley"),
(NULL, "Ringo", "Star");

INSERT INTO Type VALUES
(NULL, "Rap"),
(NULL, "RnB"),
(NULL, "HipHop"),
(NULL, "Jazz");

INSERT INTO Songs VALUES
(NULL, 1, "California Love", 2, 1),
(NULL, 2, "Locked Up", 4, 0),
(NULL, 3, "Tell Em", 5, 0),
(NULL, 4, "Jazz it up", 1, 1);
```

You see the `Rating` row/column in the table `Songs` - I want to keep a record of who rated that song and store it in another table maybe? I just want to then store the average rating. I also want to keep a record of who recommended the song as well as their details.

How would I do this? It would save me a lot of time and headaches if someone could give me the schema or idea.

Comment: Create a new table UserRating with userid, songid and rating columns. Probably a date column too, for when they rated it.

Comment: How would I link that to my songs table?

Comment: You link to the user by userID and to the song by songID. Table with `FKUserID int, FKSongID int, Rating it, RankDate datetime`. Then you can use `select songs.id, AVG(Rating) from songs inner join UserRating on UserRating.FKSongID = songs.ID group by songs.id` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new table UserRating with userid, songid and rating columns. Probably a date column too, for when they rated it. Table with `FKUserID int, FKSongID int, Rating it, RankDate datetime`.

Then you can use `select songs.id, AVG(Rating) from songs inner join UserRating on UserRating.FKSongID = songs.ID group by songs.id` Which will give you all songs by their average ranking.

Or if you need all songs rated by a user `Select * from users inner join UserRating on UserRating.FKUserID = user.ID`

or if you need all songs rated higher than 5 
`select * from songs inner join UserRating on UserRating.FKSongID = Songs.ID where rating > 5` etc etc

Comment: Thank you. What about recommendations? How would I model that

Comment: I have a `recommended` field in my `songs` table. I also want to store recommendations - like who also recommended that song

Comment: For ease of access another table with the same columns except replace ranking with recommended. Then you can use all recommended songs with `select * from songs inner join recommended on recommended.fksongid = songs.id`

Comment: Thanks - how do I only display a song once? Like three people might have recommended the same song - but I only want to see one instance of that song in my result. How do I do that?

Comment: That's probably another question but something like this `Select distinct id from songs inner join recommended on recommended.fkSongID = songs.id`

Comment: Thank you so much - just a quick one, would I need another column for count, because I also want to display the number of people who recommended it. No more questions after this, and I have accepted your answer too

Comment: No, you don't need a count column, you can use a query such as ie. `select count(*), songs.id from songs inner join recommendations on recommendations.fksongid = songs.id group by songs.id`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Much appreciated